# Android sdk manager [Process completed]

Tags: android, macos, sdk

I am working on a Mac. While in the Android sdk manager in my console, I exited the manager by hitting `CTRL + C`.

Now, when I open Library/Android/sdk/tools/android (to get back in to the sdk manager), the old session comes up in a new terminal window and still reads `[Process completed]` and I am not able to type a new command. Any tips on how to restart the sdk manager?

[this is what my sdk manager looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHP1p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for using the console instead of the interface in Android Studio?

Regardless, the `android` command is deprecated. To access the SDK Manager via the command line you should be using `Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager` to find a particular package.

Comment: Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager opens a new terminal window with the same `[Process complete]` message.

I'll navigate there through the Android Studio, but if anyone has a solution to the console - it would still be appreciated! Thanks David.

Comment: So I think you have two separate issues going on here. 1. The [Process complete] message. From this post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/975678/strange-output-from-terminal-exit-command-is-this-a-virus) it looks like your bash terminal is recording your responses in the bash sessions which can be disabled. 2. Using the SDK Manager from the CLI. The `sdkmanager` CLI gives you access to further sdk related functionality (like viewing/installing/updating packages) You can find more options from the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Comment: Ah, I see. I usually use iTerm and the [Process complete] only shows up in the regular Terminal (which is what opens when I go to use the sdkmanager). That last link you sent was helpful and it pointed me to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#sdk-manager which I will be using instead of the console for the necessary installs, just to save some time for this project. Thank you!!